# Reading very large excel file

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk, large-data

I am using this article to read a very large excel file, using SAX approach.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571.aspx

Can't store values in a DataTable or memory due to a client machine not having enough memory. Trying to read and right away store values into a database:

```
// The SAX approach.

static void ReadExcelFileSAX(string fileName)
{
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
    {

        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();

        OpenXmlReader reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart);
        string text;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.ElementType == typeof(CellValue))
            {
                text = reader.GetText();
                Console.Write(text + " ");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

For example when I read this excel file:

```
Test 1
22
345345
345345435
2333
333333
4444
4444444
324324
99999
```

I get this output:

```
Blank
22
Blank
345345
Blank 
etc
```

I have no idea where the blanks are coming from. Tried to put the if statement in there testing for blanks then I miss the last value 99999.

That reader seems so limited. Would really appreciate a suggestion, I mean anything!

Comment: Why not parse and persist the file by batching up the rows?  1000 rows at a time should be fine right?

Answer (score 1):

The `OpenXmlReader` treats the start and end elements as independant items. These can be differentiated by checking the [`IsStartElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.openxmlreader.isstartelement%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [`IsEndElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/documentformat.openxml.openxmlreader.isendelement%28v=office.14%29.aspx) properties.

Your blank values are due to the end elements where `GetText` returns the empty string.

You have 2 options to fix it. Firstly you could check for `IsStartElement` in your loop:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.ElementType == typeof(CellValue)
        && reader.IsStartElement)
    {
        text = reader.GetText();
        Console.WriteLine(text + " ");
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use the [`LoadCurrentElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/documentformat.openxml.openxmlreader.loadcurrentelement%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method to load the whole element, consuming both the start and end you were getting before:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.ElementType == typeof(CellValue))
    {
        CellValue cellVal = (CellValue)reader.LoadCurrentElement();
        Console.WriteLine(cellVal.Text);
    }
}
```